# What is the behavior of the carry flag for CP on a Game Boy?

Tags: z80, gameboy

On the page 87 of [the Game Boy CPU Manual](http://marc.rawer.de/Gameboy/Docs/GBCPUman.pdf) it is claimed that the `CP n` instruction sets the carry flag when there was no borrow and that it means that `A < n`. This seems to conflict itself, because the carry flag is set when `A > n`.

An example: If `A=0` and `B=1`, `CP B` sets the flags like `SUB A, B`, which is 0 - 1. This becomes 0 + 255 = 255 and the carry flag is not set, even though `A < B`.

I came across this same issue in other Z80 documents as well, so I don't believe this is a typo.

Am I misunderstanding how borrow and `SUB` work or is there something else going on? Is `SUB` not equal to `ADD` with two's complement in terms of flags?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The GameBoy CPU manual has it backwards. `SUB`, `SBC` and `CP` all set the carry flag when there is borrow.  If `SUB/SBC/CP A,n` is executed then carry is set if `n > A` otherwise it is clear.

This is consistent with Z-80 (and 8080) operation. As well MAME and MESS implement carry [the same way](https://github.com/mamedev/mame/blob/master/src/emu/cpu/lr35902/opc_main.inc#L81).